# What is the purpose of always locating/starting new chapters on odd pages?

Tags: print-design, design-principles, book, layout, information-architecture

I notice that in every book I have always start a new chapter in an odd page and it leads me to wonder why.

I have some written work that's about 40 pages long and 7 chapters; should I follow that rule?

If I do, the reader will definitely see blank pages before the start of a new chapter occasionally.

Why do new chapters in books usually start on an odd page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's recommended to start new chapters on the [recto page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso) of a manuscript, as it establishes a predictable flow for the reader to follow. The resulting occasional blank pages are actually a part of establishing this rhythm, making the divisions between chapters even more distinct. This recommendation is listed in [rule 1.48](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch01/ch01_sec048.html) <sup>requires login</sup> of *the Chicago Manual of Style*.

The recto page is considered the front of each leaf, and is the right-hand page when dealing left-to-right languages.

You can find interesting discussions on the various options and arguments for starting chapters at [Five Rainbows](http://fiverainbows.com/5rainbows/2013/05/to-recto-of-not-to-recto/) and [Ask MetaFilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/202383/Why-do-we-start-chapters-on-the-righthand-page).

Comment: I couldn't find a better source for the CMoS rule, but the book should be freely available in the reference section of most libraries, though I highly recommend purchasing it if you intend to set any amount of text in a semi-professional manner.

Comment: "The usability of a system is improved when similar parts are expressed in similar ways." For one, it's much easier to flick through a book to find a chapter if you know which side to look for the start of the chapter on.

Comment: @justinthrelkeld: I read somewhere that the book of Robin William: The Non-Designer's Design Book is also a very good one. Have you read it? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @Ooker *[The Non-designer's Design Book](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/12778547987391668247)* is an alright resource too. Though it's much more general and basic than CMoS. I had it assigned during one of my university courses and ended up selling it because it wasn't as useful as other books. If you'd like, I can point you to a list of the books I keep on my shelf and a summary of why I keep them around.

Comment: @justinthrelkeld: if you have time, then this is great :D

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter: a very good source made by you. Although, the answers are lack of images, which is of course a very big completeness in any tutorial for graphic :D

Comment: @Ooker: if you're still interested, I finally published my list of books I keep around: http://justinthrelkeld.github.io/designbooks — feel free to contact me via [other channels](http://twitter.com/justinthrelkeld) if you have questions (before this gets too terribly off-topic).